# System.out.print does not print to the console otherwise new line is printed

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have simple Java code, which should print 5 lines of text, 4 with new line and last without new line. Unfortunately it does not work and only first four lines are being printed and last is being printed only if new line is printed in the end of it or after it:

```
System.out.println("   1. Workers list");
System.out.println("   2. Add worker");
System.out.println("   3. Remove worker");
System.out.println("   4. Backup copy");
System.out.print("Choice> ");
```

I tried adding `System.out.flush();` after `System.out.print("Choice> ");` to force printing, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way some consoles work, they only output full lines. If this is happening to you in IntelliJ IDEA, it's just the way IDEA's console works.

If you run that from a normal terminal, you'll see the partial line.

Answer (score 0):

println method in OutputStream class is as below.

```
 public void println(String x) {
        synchronized (this) {
            print(x);
            newLine();
        }
    }
```

which means println method prints the line and then add a new line and print method just prints the line.